# Is there any Way to Present a ViewController from Top without using Custom Classes?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I want to present a TableViewController from top on a button Click.I am able to present it using Custom Classes.Is there anyway to Present it without using Custom Classes so that it wont crash in iOS Versions?

```
popOverViewController = [[ACCPopoverViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[popOverViewController setTheMainArray:self.popoverListArray];
[popOverViewController setPopinTransitionStyle:BKTPopinTransitionStyleSpringySlide];//[self transitionStyleForIndexPath:0]];
if ([self isDismissable]) {
    [popOverViewController setPopinOptions:BKTPopinDefault];
} else {
    [popOverViewController setPopinOptions:BKTPopinDisableAutoDismiss];
}
[popOverViewController setDelegatePopOverIphone:self];
[popOverViewController setPopinTransitionDirection:BKTPopinTransitionDirectionTop];
[self.navigationController presentPopinController:popOverViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"Popin presented !");
}];
}
```

Here i am using a Custom PopOver...

then I used this to animate

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.1
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     self.popoverView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }];
[self.view addSubview:self.popoverView];
```

but it shows some issues in ios 7.0 not in 7.1.
Donno why?
Checked the 6.0 and greater and i checked the constraints.
Pardon me if i am doing Wrong.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use UIView animations, and add the view of the tableViewController as a subview to your main view.

Comment: Nop thats not working i tried that too..!!! if you have some code snippets can you please share that?

Comment: How about you add some code snippets of what you have now, and I will try to update it to suit your needs?

Comment: @Wodjefer Please add code from your app to illustrate what you're trying to do and the attempts you've made to solve.